# Swift change an element value in matrix by 3 arrays

Tags: arrays, swift

I have defined the class B:

```
class B {
    var b : Int = 0
    init(){}
    init(b : Int) {
        self.b = b
    }
 }
```

And, a matrix with 3 arrays:

```
var k : [[[B]]] = [[[B]]] (repeating: [[B]] (repeating: [B] (repeating: B(b: -1), count: 2), count: 4), count: 3)
```

Now, I want to change value for only a element: **k[0][1][1].b = 7**

But all values of k are affected to new value is **7**.

What's solution for that?

Comment: `class B` is a *reference type,* therefore all array elements reference the same instance. – Using a `struct B` would be the easiest solution.

Comment: Great. Thanks Martin R.